# Dynamically change the background of a cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I don't know JavaScript, but I want to use the function to change the background color of several cards.

```js
function SetColorRed() {
  document.getElementById("SettingCard").style.background = "red";
}
function SetColorBlue() {
  document.getElementById("SettingCard").style.background = "blue";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="SettingCard" id="SettingCard">
        <div class="dropdown col-sm">
          <a class="dsh253" href="#" role="button" id="SetColorCardBG" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            BackgroundColor
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dsh250" aria-labelledby="SetColorCardBG">
            <div class="dshcd250">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="SetColorRed();">Red</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="SetColorBlue();">Blue</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h4><b>02 / Einteilung MA Arbeitsgruppe / Wohnung</b></h4>
        <p>Einteilung der gleichen MA-Arbeitsgruppen in die gleichen <i>Wohnungen</i> / Häuser 2022-06- 27 in Arbeit</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end card -->
      <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------- -->
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="SettingCard" id="SettingCard">
        <div class="dropdown col-sm">
          <a class="dsh253" href="#" role="button" id="SetColorCardBG" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            BackgroundColor
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dsh250" aria-labelledby="SetColorCardBG">
            <div class="dshcd250">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="SetColorRed();">Red</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="SetColorBlue();">Blue</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h4><b>02 / Einteilung MA Arbeitsgruppe / Wohnung</b></h4>
        <p>Einteilung der gleichen MA-Arbeitsgruppen in die gleichen <i>Wohnungen</i> / Häuser 2022-06- 27 in Arbeit</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end Card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I add the cards from `phpMyAdmin`, and I want each card to have the function of changing the background color, with the `BackgroundColor` button, the background color changes only to the first card, Is there a way for a javascript code to work for all the cards as I presented in the code above?

Comment: dont tag in the title, use the tags!

Comment: IDs need to be unique

Comment: @mplungjan Cards are added from phpmyadmin if I change their id and make them unique then the javascript code must be duplicated and if I have 100 cards per page it is the problem with javascript a lot of spam

Comment: Why not simply target their class?

Comment: YOu want to change all the cards or only the specfic card that is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another selector than ID since IDs need to be unique

Here is a delegated version

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('a');
    if (tgt && tgt.matches('.dropdown-item')) { 
      tgt.closest('.SettingCard').style.background = tgt.textContent.trim().toLowerCase()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="SettingCard">
        <div class="dropdown col-sm">
          <a class="dsh253" href="#" role="button" id="SetColorCardBG" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            BackgroundColor
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dsh250" aria-labelledby="SetColorCardBG">
            <div class="dshcd250">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item">Red</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item">Blue</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h4><b>02 / Einteilung MA Arbeitsgruppe / Wohnung</b></h4>
        <p>Einteilung der gleichen MA-Arbeitsgruppen in die gleichen <i>Wohnungen</i> / Häuser 2022-06- 27 in Arbeit</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end card -->
      <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------- -->
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="SettingCard">
        <div class="dropdown col-sm">
          <a class="dsh253" href="#" role="button" id="SetColorCardBG" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            BackgroundColor
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dsh250" aria-labelledby="SetColorCardBG">
            <div class="dshcd250">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item">Red</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item">Blue</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h4><b>02 / Einteilung MA Arbeitsgruppe / Wohnung</b></h4>
        <p>Einteilung der gleichen MA-Arbeitsgruppen in die gleichen <i>Wohnungen</i> / Häuser 2022-06- 27 in Arbeit</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end Card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the code is perfect, I doubled the cards and everything works very well

Answer (score 0):

All card ID's need to be unique, therefore you could change your javascript to this:

```
function SetColorRed(index) {
  document.getElementById("SettingCard-" + index).style.background = "red";
}
function SetColorBlue(index) {
  document.getElementById("SettingCard-" + index).style.background = "blue";
}
```

Then when you are pulling the cards from the database, add a index to them in the `id` which increases per card so the ids for each card would now be: `id="SettingCard-1"` `id="SettingCard-2"` etc

When you then call your functions, you would pass in that same index on the card: `onclick="SetColorBlue(index);"`

Let me know if you need any further clarification.